# Uninstall Kubuntu dual boot with WIndows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, kubuntu

So I have been using Kubuntu together with Windows 10 in a dual boot for a year and a half. Now I got a bit tired of Kubuntu so I wanted to change (maybe to MXLinux or Manjaro). I have seen a lot of answers related to this, but I don't really know which is the right way. Could anyone tell me or point out the correct answer on how to safely and correctly delete Ubuntu partition so in the future I can install another Linux distro? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to delete the Kubuntu, you just install whatever OS you decide to use  over the top of it.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do anything like this BACKUP YOUR DATA!!! :)

I think the OP wants to delete the partition then maybe, later on, decide if he wants to install another Linux distro.
I think the right way to do it is to delete and extend the volume in Windows Disk Manager, then repair the windows bootloader (as grub deletes the Windows bootloader). There are many tutorials on how to do this but here is one I found using a quick google.

[How to Uninstall a Linux Dual-Boot System From Your Computer](https://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/)